# yfinance: same datafetch code not working in 2 different files

Tags: python, python-requests, yfinance

I have created the following class for a project I am working on:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd


class StockData:
    def __init__(self, ticker, period="1y"):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.ticker_info = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info
        self.historical_data = self.get_historical_data(period)
        self.pe = self.get_pe_ratio()
        self.mcap = self.get_market_cap()

    def get_historical_data(self, period="1y", interval="1d"):
        # Fetch historical data for the given period and interval
        historical_data = yf.download(self.ticker, period=period, interval=interval)
        return historical_data

    def get_pe_ratio(self):
        # Get the P/E ratio of the company
        pe_ratio = self.ticker_info.get('trailingPE', None)  # If 'trailingPE' key is not present, set it to None
        return pe_ratio

    def get_market_cap(self):
        # Get the market cap of the company
        market_cap = self.ticker_info.get('marketCap', None)  # If 'marketCap' key is not present, set it to None
        return market_cap
```

I have a file called test.py in the same folder, where if I give the following code, it works without issues:

```
from StockData import StockData

stock_obj = StockData('ASHOKLEY.NS', '3y')
print(stock_obj.mcap)
```

I have the following code in main.py (also in the same folder):

```
import pandas as pd
from StockData import StockData

sector_dict = {
    'Auto': ['ASHOKLEY', 'BAJAJ-AUTO', 'BALKRISIND'],
    'Bank': ['AUBANK', 'AXISBANK', 'BANDHANBANK']
}

for sector, companies in sector_dict.items():
    sector_dict[sector] = [company + '.NS' for company in companies]

for sector, companies in sector_dict.items():
    for company in companies:
        print(company)
        temp = StockData(company, period='3y')
        print(temp.mcap)
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

```
ASHOKLEY.NS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\FinProj\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    temp = StockData(company, period='3y')
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\FinProj\StockData.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.ticker_info = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\ticker.py", line 138, in info
    return self.get_info()
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 1501, in get_info
    data = self._quote.info
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\scrapers\quote.py", line 563, in info
    self._fetch(self.proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\scrapers\quote.py", line 592, in _fetch
    result = self._data.get_raw_json(
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 75, in get_raw_json
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/ASHOKLEY.NS?modules=summaryProfile%2CfinancialData%2CquoteType%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CassetProfile%2CsummaryDetail&ssl=true
```

In my head, these are the exact same codes, unless I am missing something. I tried deliberately slowing down the code and googling but got no working solutions. Is there some error I am not catching?

Comment: I was able to run your code without hitting the 401 error you got. Could it be a rate limit by Yahoo Finance? I did get a 404 because BANDHANBANK.NS does not exist in Yahoo Finance.